# Calling unknown method: yii\mongodb\ActiveQuery::groupBy()

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

```
$all_sequence=Mymodel::find()->groupBy('eventsid')->where(['>','sequence',0])->all();
```

It shows
 `Calling unknown method: yii\mongodb\ActiveQuery::groupBy()`

How to achieve `groupBy` in mongodb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is - you can't. `yii\mongodb\ActiveQuery` don't have `groupBy()` method (propably because mongodb don't have `group by` clausule). You can group results on [`yii\mongodb\Collection`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-collection.html) level, by using `group` method.

[Group()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-collection.html#group()-detail) performs aggregation using Mongo "group" command.